# Show/Hide div as per <select> tag value using ng-if

Tags: angularjs

I tried to implement a simple logic as per  [the JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/nq1eyj1v/1/)

Here is my   [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/irDyvcNJjuClLQB9Fk91?p=preview)

```
<select ng-model="mod" ng-click="foo();" ng-dropdown required>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
</select>
{{ modRes2 = (mod === 'B')}}

<div id="a" ng-if="{{mod === 'A'}}">a</div>
<div id="d" ng-if=modRes2>b</div>
```

Here A doesnt on work on selecting the option 'A', but B shows and hides just fine. Refer to the plunk above.

The jsfiddle example that I am following is built on angular version 1.2.x, and I am using angular version 1.4.x. Can this be the reason?

Comment: . I have the same doubt with @rameshRajendran. Why you want div tag? I think Ramesh rajendran suggestion is find out your wrong way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
<div id="a" ng-if="{{mod === 'A'}}">a</div>
```

to

```
<div id="a" ng-if="mod === 'A'">a</div>
```

ng-if directive takes an [angular expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)
the {{}} syntax is for marking an angular expression outside of an angular directive. Angular assumes the input into ng-* directives are angular expressions

I suggest going through the [angular tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) and the [angular guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide)

Answer (score 2):

you don't need the handlebars in ngif

```
<div id="a" ng-if="mod === 'A'">a</div>
```

Comment: I am new to angular js, my assumption was that it was used everytime to resolve an expression.  Didn't notice it wasn't there in the tut that I was following.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need curly braces for ng-if tag. ng-if takes expression

```
 <div id="a" ng-if="mod === 'A'">a</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<div id="a" ng-if="{{mod === 'A'}}">a</div>
```

to

```
<div id="a" ng-if="mod === 'A'">a</div>
```

You may try it out [HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/DLHDPp93avQ0JhJcEPWE?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are give a solution to you. **But my answer for a suggestion for you.**

Actually Why you using `ng-if` condition and why you writing so many `div`?

I think you need just show the selected dropdown value, then why you need more div ? so just try below way

```
<select ng-model="mod" ng-click="foo();" ng-dropdown required>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
</select>

{{mod}}
```

That's all.

Comment: This was just a quick POC, towards the possibility of hiding and showing multple html controls based on a selected value. Your option doesnt really allow that